# ¿Como evitar que un usuario externo abra la consola de nuestra aplicación?

Tags: javascript, html, web, seguridad, consola

He visto que muchas paginas tienen deshabilitado la función para navegar en la consola, me ha surgido una gran duda de como se puede hacer esto en mi aplicación web.

Quisiera prevenir ataques y para tener una aplicación mucho más segura.

Comment: No lo he hecho todavía en mis aplicaciones, pero quizás este [link](https://davidwalsh.name/disable-console) pueda ayudarte

Comment: No puedes, eso es una función del navegador no de tu sitio web.

Comment: Exacto, no puedes! Lo único que te queda es impedir un clic derecho para que por lo menos se le dificulte a alguien buscar la herramienta de desarrollo.

Answer (score 3):

**No puedes.**

Las *herramientas de desarrollador* o *developer tools* están del lado del cliente y las proveen los navegadores web.

Lo único que debes hacer es asegurarte de que tu código del lado del cliente no tenga nada que ver con tu código del servidor ya que de ser así tienes serios problemas de diseño por resolver.